# JSON-LD unmarshalling getting error "jsonld: fetching remote contexts is disabled"

Tags: go, unmarshalling, json-ld

I am trying to unmarshall JSON-LD using package https://godoc.org/github.com/emersion/go-jsonld

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"   
    jsonld "github.com/emersion/go-jsonld"
)
func main() {

    text := `{"@context": ["http://schema.org", { "image": { "@id": "schema:image", "@type": "@id"}  }],"id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q76","type": "Person","name": "Barack Obama","givenName": "Barack","familyName": "Obama","jobTitle": "44th President of the United States","image": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:President_Barack_Obama.jpg"}`
    textBytes := []byte(text)
    var container interface{}
    err := jsonld.Unmarshal(textBytes,container)
    fmt.Println("Error while unmarshalling json-ld: ",err.Error())
    fmt.Println("Output: ",container)
}
```

> Output

```
Error while unmarshalling json-ld:  jsonld: fetching remote contexts is disabled
Output:  <nil>
```

I also checked other function for unmarshalling in same package like `func UnmarshalWithContext(b []byte, v interface{}, ctx *Context) error` but no help.

Comment: `UnmarshalWithContext` is unrelated to fetching remote data.

Comment: @Flimzy Any doc where it is mentioned, sir ?

Comment: Yes. In the doc you linked to: https://godoc.org/github.com/emersion/go-jsonld#UnmarshalWithContext

Comment: @Flimzy I referred doc  copying line from it "UnmarshalWithContext parses the JSON-LD-encoded data with the context ctx and stores the result in the value pointed to by v." , reason I thought it will fetch remote data because it is having 3rd arg as a context which is a struct and having one of the field as "URL". Hope I made my point sir.

Comment: The context argument may be relevant to aborting a remote fetch if it cancels, but it won't magically tell the parser _how_ to fetch remote data.

Comment: @Flimzy Had no idea about this, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a remote context in the input, so you need either fetch it as in:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    jsonld "github.com/emersion/go-jsonld"
)

type person struct {
    ID    string           `jsonld:"@id"`
    Name  string           `jsonld:"name"`
    URL   *jsonld.Resource `jsonld:"url"`
    Image *jsonld.Resource `jsonld:"image"`
}

func main() {

    text := `{"@context": ["http://schema.org", { "image": { "@id": "schema:image", "@type": "@id"}  }],"id": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q76","type": "Person","name": "Barack Obama","givenName": "Barack","familyName": "Obama","jobTitle": "44th President of the United States","image": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:President_Barack_Obama.jpg"}`
    textBytes := []byte(text)
    var container person
    dec := jsonld.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(textBytes))
    dec.FetchContext = func(url string) (*jsonld.Context, error) {
        var fetchedContext jsonld.Context //TODO fetch the context
        return &fetchedContext, nil
    }

    err := dec.Decode(&container)
    fmt.Println("Error while unmarshalling json-ld: ", err)
    fmt.Println("Output: ", container)
}
```

Or provide the schema in the input. You can refer to [tests](https://github.com/emersion/go-jsonld/blob/401cba701428835b62b3c8a8ea83fff1207f73dd/jsonld_test.go#L260) as examples of input and output.